# In Angular 2, How can I remove click event from a component / directive, if "click" was attached directly in an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 that comes with Angular 4. I built a component that takes the original `(click)` event from current element and binds it to a new one (dinamically created in the component). What I'm trying to do, is to remove the original click event from current component.

**HTML**

```html
<!-- imageZoom() is defined in my view controller: page.ts -->
<inline-spinner
    [src]="http://..."
    (click)="imageZoom($event)"></inline-spinner>
```

**COMPONENT**

```ts
export class InlineSpinnerComponent implements OnChanges {

    public img: any;

    @Output() click: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {

        this.img = new Image();

        // I want to unbind/remove "click" from here if possible.
        // this.elementRef.nativeElement = <inline-spinner>
    }

    ngOnChanges() {

        // Just to show what I'm doing with the original click event
        this.img.addEventListener('click', () => { this.click.emit(this.img); });
    }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you can change `(click)="imageZoom($event)"` to `(click)="isDisabled || imageZoom($event)"`, you could use the `isDisabled` variable to "remove" the listener from `inline-spinner`.

Comment: isDisabled would be part of my component? What's its scope?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are looking for something like this. This should be in a directive, that you attach to the element on which you want neutralize the click.

It will check if the the click event comes from the concerned component only and in that case only do Nothing

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    onClick(event: Event, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        if(this.elementRef.nativeElement ==== targetElement){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure how to encapsulate this into my component. I'm using Ionic 3 (TypeScript + Angular 4) and it might be that MouseEvent is not the right choice since my code is part of an hybrid mobile app. Any advice?

Comment: Nop, sorry. I think this is not the way to deal with this. My component is an image preloader and my app loads galleries with lots of images (lazy loading with infinite scroll), so every time it's called, a new listener will be attached and for every click, hundreds of click events would be fired. I like your solution and did something similar in the past (I remembered then) implementing a directive with a fallback for failing images. But what I need in this case is just a method similar to removeEventListener() or a way to achieve this without knowing the attached function.

Comment: I "fixed" it with a workaround in imageZoom, just checking the existence of a known property and stopping the action to avoid clicks/taps before the new element loads. But if I want to distribute this component (which is the idea), I need it to be able to handle this situation itself instead of trusting the developer to add additional code in their custom function.

Comment: I mixed up  stopPropagation() with preventDefault(). Please give it a try!!

Comment: I know those and yes, they work in certain scenarios. In this one, I would need to be able to modify the custom user function from inside the component to delegate a stopPropagation or be the same tag (I replace the current one "<inline-spinner>" with a new one "<img>") to be able to attach preventDefault(). BTW, I'll try something with preventDefault before all this, that's a good idea.